# $ (k\otimes h^\ast)^\ast=h\otimes k^\ast$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $H,K$ be Hilbert spaces with $h\in H,k\in K$. Let $k\otimes h^\ast(g)= \left\langle g,h \right\rangle k$. I'm supposed to prove $ (k\otimes h^\ast)^\ast=h\otimes k^\ast$, but I don't see how this makes any sense, since

$$\left\langle k\otimes h^\ast (x),y \right\rangle =\left\langle \left\langle x,h \right\rangle k,y \right\rangle = \left\langle k,\left\langle h,x \right\rangle  y \right\rangle $$
and

$$ \left\langle x,h\otimes k^\ast (y) \right\rangle = \left\langle x, \left\langle y,k \right\rangle ,h \right\rangle = \left\langle \left\langle k,y \right\rangle x,h \right\rangle $$
which do not seem even remotely the same...

Comment: Well the inner product is bilinear, so you can take the scalars out...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi hahaha thanks! Sorry!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  I think you meant *sesquilinear*.

Comment: @Batominovski If it's over $\mathbb{C}$, yes, it is sesquilinear.